# Change bootstrap accordion drop down icon for open and closed body using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using jQuery it will be possible to alter the chevron class of the accordion header clicked so that when the body is not displayed it shows a chevron pointing right and when it is displayed it shows a chevron pointing down. I'm just having some trouble with it.

I have attempted things around this idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#first-panel').on('click', function(){

        if($('#first-panel-span').is(":visible") ){
            $('#first-panel-span').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right');
            $('#first-panel-span').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down');
        } else {
            $('#first-panel-span').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right');
            $('#first-panel-span').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down');
            $('#first-panel-span').css("display", "block");
        }

    });

});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ycryphah/1/

I have looked at other answers but they don't quite apply to my needs.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7r0tjLr5/

```
        if($('#first-panel-span').is(":visible") ){
        $('#first-panel-span').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-right');
    }
```

try this. BTW you had your jquery in css window.

Comment: Actually you can remove the if clause as well :)